# All users/groups in vSphere set to read-only for a guest

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

For one of my Server2k8 VMs on an ESXi host, I accidentally set all vSphere users/groups to read-only so all vSphere management options are disabled. We can log into the ESXi host as root and manage the VM but it does not show us the vSphere users so we can't change them from read-only back to administrator.

Are there any vSphere CLI options or other work arounds to fix this? Fortunately it's not in production yet so I could always blow it up.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[VMware describes the procedure for ESX](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1031192) and it's very similar for ESXi.

Enable SSH on the console and logon as root. Navigate to the `/etc/vmware/hostd` directory and edit `authorization.xml`. Look for the `<ACEDataRoleId>` entry for root (it'll be inside the same `<ACEData>` as an `<ACEDataUser>` set to `root`). Change the value in `<ACEDataRoleId>`
to `-1`. Switch back to the menu on console 2 and restart the management agents.